Postgres - ORA-08177 when inserting into Foreign Table
I've seen a lot of posts for this error:  ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
I just upgraded to Postgres 14, from Postgres 10 as I thought maybe it was due to such an old version of Postgres.   I re-tried the INSERT statement, and still received the same error.
I saw this posting:  ORA-08177: can't serialize access for the transaction with oracle_FDW
So, I tried that:
postgres=# alter server oracle_dev options ( set isolation_level 'read_committed');
ERROR:  option "isolation_level" not found

Is there something I am missing?  Some supporting info:
postgres=# SELECT oracle_diag('oracle_dev');
                                                   oracle_diag                                                       
oracle_fdw 2.6.0, PostgreSQL 14.11 (Ubuntu 14.11-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), Oracle client 21.13.0.0.0, Oracle server 12.2.0.1.0

Any help would be great.
Regards.
